# Which HTML elements can't contain child nodes?

Tags: html, dom, specifications, children

I've been looking for an exhaustive list, but can't find one anywhere. To avoid having to trawl through the specs, does anyone know what they are (and I suppose a complementary list of elements that can contain children would be useful too).

And how much does this list vary between XHTML 1 and HTML5?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can find a list of void elements (elements that cannot have any child content) in the [HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/syntax.html#void-elements).

With the exception of the new elements introduced in HTML5, the list of void elements in XHTML is the same.

Comment: In regex format in case you need it: `/^(AREA|BASE|BR|COL|COMMAND|EMBED|HR|IMG|INPUT|KEYGEN|LINK|META|PARAM|SOURCE|TRACK|WBR)$/`

Comment: Or `[ 'AREA', 'BASE', 'BR', 'COL', 'COMMAND', 'EMBED', 'HR', 'IMG', 'INPUT', 'KEYGEN', 'LINK', 'META', 'PARAM', 'SOURCE', 'TRACK', 'WBR']` if you want to use `Array.prototype.includes(tagName)`