# radio button in conjunction with c3 does not show text

Tags: html, d3.js, c3

I am creating a custom legend, that contains radio inputs, of a pie chart  created with c3.
I create radio inputs via D3 API. 
I haven't been able to show the text on the side of radio input.

```
d3.select('.container').insert('div', '.chart')
   .selectAll('input')
   .data(['data', 'data10', 'data5'])
   .enter().append('input')    
   .attr('type', function (id) { return 'radio'; })
   .attr('name', function (id) { return id;})
   .attr('value', function (id) { return id;})
   .append('span')
   .html(function (id) { return id; });
```

Here is the css:

```
input{
    width:31.5%;    
}
input span{    
    color:red;
    background-color: green;
}
```

None of it has any effect. Here is my [full jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agcsi/1vk25ma8/3/).
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're having is you're appending your `<span>` to be a child of the `<input>`, i.e. `<input><span></span></input>`. This is invalid HTML, as `<input>`s are [void elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-elements) and therefore *can't have children* ([also see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898374/which-html-elements-cant-contain-child-nodes)).

Instead, you can wrap both elements in a `<div>` (i.e. `<div><input></input><span><span></div>`) like so:

```
// Append a div for each different data type
var divs = d3.select('.container')
    .insert('div', '.chart')
    .selectAll('input')
    .data(['data', 'data10', 'data5'])
    .enter().append('div');

// Add a child input to each div
divs.append("input")
    .attr('type', function (id) { return 'radio'; })
    .attr('name', function (id) { return id;})
    .attr('value', function (id) { return id;})

// Add a child span to each div
divs.append('span')
     .html(function (id) { return id; })
```

which looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

Updated [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mdml/5j2v7n68/).